# QML Canvas Qt6 - Cannot assign to non-existent property "onPaint"

Tags: qt, qml

I'm working on a project in **Qt6**, utilizing **Qt Design Studio**.

I'm currently facing an issue related to a `Canvas` element in **QML**. Specifically, I'm trying to use the `onPaint` signal handler, but I encounter the following error:

> Cannot assign to non-existent property "onPaint"

I've already ensured that I'm importing both `QtQuick 2.15` and `QtQuick.Controls 2.15`.
Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

...

Canvas {
    id: canvas
    anchors.fill: parent

    onPaint: {
        // Some code...
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting this error and how I can resolve it?

Additional info:

- Qt Version: 6.4.0
- Qt Design Studio Version: 3.9.0

**EDIT 1**:

As suggested, I have removed the version numbers from the imports, but the error still occurs.

New code:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Canvas {
    onPaint: {
        // Some code...
```

Comment: The `2.15` imports are appropriate for Qt5 projects. Because you indicated yours is Qt6, you should remove the version numbers from your imports.

Comment: Could it be that you have something in your project that obfuscated Qt's Canvas? This could happen say, if you had a Canvas.qml ?

Comment: I have checked and the loaded Canvas is the right one, I don't have any other custom component which overwrite Qt Canvas

Comment: If you are certain you are using the correct Canvas, declaring onPaint should work. There must be something that explains it. Here's another thing to try: `import QtQuick as C`. Then use `C.Canvas { }`. This should explicitly force it to load `Canvas` from `QtQuick` and not anywhere else.

Comment: Using this solution works, I don't know why it is necessary but it works.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, it wasn't meant to be a solution, but, it confirms that there is ambiguity with the `Canvas` in your project. The above test confirms that if you explicitly request the one from QtQuick it works, so, the one you're getting by default, unfortunately, is coming from elsewhere. It is up to you to figure it out, as, it could require some degree of troubleshooting to narrow it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qt6.x documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-canvas.html  actually has a mistake. It should not include a version number in the import line imports:

```
import QtQuick
Canvas {
    id: mycanvas
    width: 100
    height: 200
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAABYXicdY9NDoIwFIT3PcULbjAxBIgmiHHFBfw5QS21NNSW1OcPMdzdUhF14Us382U6mZGnxliELW4vktVE/sioMBqtUWeyoYLDg4A7WebQOOnFgbJaWHPRDu44Q6qFckZgRhmbQzDJ5lm2XATQeXtB9ZWeh6B32KllHo/wJkusckjieEQVl6LCHNIvZvSGSu3gJ66/K7XA8A5rEBz7AfyOYZCWwXT143Oe6CiV2mPrKq/d5siKAw2TGcT+JX8+9DvDl8U3nQ3tvuyvtR3pCHkC1x9edw==)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have removed the version numbers from QtQuick and QtQuick.Controls but the error still occurs. 
I have also replaced my code with yours, but the error is still there.